# .load() Jquery function load duplicate window in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the Jquery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr[href]').click(function(event) {
    $('tr[href]').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#profile').load('home/users/1');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Every time I click the target, I found the .load function load the window double times the last click. For example, in the rails log it shows several `Started GET "/home/users/1`in the same time thus my app becomes slow and slow. Below is the view file where the window is loaded:

```
<div class="col-md-5" >
  <div class="table table-responsive" >
    <div id='list' >
    <% if params[:q] == 'a' %>
      <%= render 'users' %>
    <% elsif params[:q] == 'b' %>
      <%= render 'jobs_index' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'lineitems' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <div id="profile">//load the window
</div>
```

Could any body tell me why this occurs? Very thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
I modified the code `$('#profile').load('home/users/1');` in application.js as below:

```
var url="home/users/"+$(this).attr("href")
$('#profile-outline').load(url+" #special");
```

And add a in the outermost of the html file.Then the problem is solved.
In summary, just use load("url #container") to replace load("url").